# JScience Java Units Bar to Psi

Tags: java, jscience

Is there any straight forward way to convert **bar** to **psi**(Pounds per square inch)?, like converting mm to inch

```
   //mm to inches
    Unit<Length> mm = SI.MILLIMETER;
    Unit<Length> in = NonSI.INCH;
    UnitConverter toInch = mm.getConverterTo(in);

    double d1 = toInch.convert(Measure.valueOf(10.0,mm).doubleValue(mm));
    Measure<Double, ? extends Quantity> convert1 = Measure.valueOf(d1, in);
    System.out.println(convert1);
```

I can convert it by multiplying (1 bar = 14.5037738 psi to the value) manually, But is there any other way to achieve below lines of code?

```
 //bar to psi
    Unit<Pressure> bar = NonSI.BAR;
    Unit<? extends Quantity> psi = NonSI.POUND.divide(NonSI.INCH.pow(2));
    UnitConverter toPsi = bar.getConverterTo(psi);// not compitable error

    double d2 = toPsi.convert(Measure.valueOf(10.0,bar).doubleValue(bar));
    Measure<Double, ? extends Quantity> convert2 = Measure.valueOf(d2, psi);
            System.out.println(convert2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `POUND_FORCE` instead of `POUND`.

`POUND_FORCE.divide( INCH.pow(2) ).getConverterTo( BAR )`